# Hybrid Intel/AMD Radeon problem

Tags: drivers, ati, intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 7520 which is Ubuntu certificated.
I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. Now i have problem with the fan control (noise) because of the hybrid System.

I tried some tutorials but they didn't worked very well.
I have a

- Intel HD Graphics 4000
- AMD Radeon HD 7730M
  in my laptop.

Hope anybody can help me.
cheers

Comment: *puuussshh* (Y)